# Getting Matched Index value from SQL database in HTML/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know how to echo value in dropdown in php?
Suppose I am getting $Selectedcurrency = "Euro"; from the database.

And below is my dropdown:

```
<select name='currencies' id="currencies"  onchange="setForm(this.value)">
 <option value=''>Kindly Select The Currecy</option>
 <option value='USD'>USD</option>
 <option value='AUD'>AUD</option>
 <option value='EURO'>EURO</option>
</select>
```

I want the dropdown will show the matched saved value comming from the database ie: `$Selectedcurrency = "Euro";`

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can use `selected` along with if statements**

**TRY THIS:**

```
<?php
$Selectedcurrency = 'EURO';
?>

<select name='currencies' id="currencies"  onchange="setForm(this.value)">
 <option value='' <?php if($Selectedcurrency == '') { echo "selected"; } ?>>Kindly Select The Currecy</option>
 <option value='USD' <?php if($Selectedcurrency == 'USD') { echo "selected"; } ?>>USD</option>
 <option value='AUD' <?php if($Selectedcurrency == 'AUD') { echo "selected"; } ?>>AUD</option>
 <option value='EURO' <?php if($Selectedcurrency == 'EURO') { echo "selected"; } ?>>EURO</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ternary operator** here will be more elegant from my point of view.

```
<select name='currencies' id="currencies"  onchange="setForm(this.value)">
     <option value=''>Kindly Select The Currecy</option>
     <option <?php echo (($Selectedcurrency !== "USD") ?: "selected"); ?> value='USD'>
      USD
     </option>
     <option <?php echo (($Selectedcurrency !== "AUD") ?: "selected"); ?> value='AUD'>
      AUD
     </option>
     <option <?php echo (($Selectedcurrency !== "EURO") ?: "selected"); ?> value='EURO'>
      EURO
     </option>
</select>
```